# undefined reference to 'QNetworkAccessManager'

Tags: c++, qt

i'm new to QT API and the QT IDE, i was following this tutorial: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt, but when i try to compile i get this errors, the usually cause of the problem is: the compiler couldn't
 find the .cpp/.lib archive where the code for the methods are, but in this case, the api would be already configured, i can't understand why i'm getting this error, and also i couldn't find the project properties, here is my test code:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
```

this is the headers included on the mainwindow.hpp file, now the mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
         this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url("http://www.forum.nokia.wiki");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}
```

finishedSlot method:

```
void MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    //nothing
}
```

so this is the code, if someone can help i'll thank you :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do you have `QT += network` in the .pro project file?

Edit:
fixed typo, was config instead of QT

Comment: It is supposed to be _QT_, not config: _QT += network_ and don't forget to _run qmake_ from build menu.

Comment: here is the error: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\untitled\mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN21QNetworkAccessManagerC1EP7QObject'

Answer (score 4):

I solved this for CMake by appending following lines to the **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Network)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cmake just add ${QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARY} to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my CMakeLists.txt fixed the problem for me:

```
target_link_libraries(WeatherWidget PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network)
```